# Is it normal to see two varnishd processes?

Tags: varnish

I'm running Varnish 3.x on a RHEL5 server. After starting varnish, `ps ax |grep varnish` gives:

```
[root@ip-... ec2-user]# ps ax |grep varnish
 2747 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/idea-int.vcl -u varnish -g varnish
 2748 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/idea-int.vcl -u varnish -g varnish
```

And `/var/run/varnish.pid` shows 2747.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. One handles normal connections, the other handles the admin.

You can check which is which by using `netstat`:

```
# netstat -ntlp | grep varnish
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8935/varnishd   
tcp    0  0 127.0.0.1:6082   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8934/varnishd
```

As you can see one binds to the admin port (6082) on the loopback interface, while the other binds to the main port (80 in my case and in most).